# Format aggregated DateTime in Kendo Grid when ServerOperation is true

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a column in Kendo Grid for DateTime's:

```
columns.Bound(typeof(DateTime), "MyDateTimeColumn").ClientFooterTemplate("#= kendo.toString(min, 'yyyy/MM/dd') #")
```

As you can see I have defined format for footer and it works fine, but only when I have ServerOperation(false) defined in DataSource. When I switch ServerOperation to TRUE, the data displayed in footer is something like "/Date(1384124400000)/".

How to make Kendo Grid format aggregated DateTime in footer in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution turned out to be so easy. I had to use kendo.parseDate function:

```
columns.Bound(typeof(DateTime), "MyDateTimeColumn").ClientFooterTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(min), 'yyyy/MM/dd') #")
```